# API for sending a letter to congress/senate?

Tags: api

I am creating a website that will have a "Send this letter as an email to your Congress/Senate representative" functionality. I have found a few APIs that provide physical addresses, but I am looking for email addresses. Does anyone know of an API that will allow this functionality (paid or free)? I would need to look up the representatives by zip code. Thanks.

Comment: `cat >/dev/null` for all the good it will do anybody. Sorry, I shouldn't be snarky.  Seriously, see this: http://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2012/01/19/dont-use-zipcodes/

Comment: I also have lat/long available to use, and it looks like that is the best method for the Sunlight Foundation APIs. That is great information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, email addresses for senators are no longer published. Going with a 3rd party service, CQRC Engage.